# How can I prove a sequence of values follows a certain closed form equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

For example, imagine I'm trying to do this

$$
(1-3x+3x^2)/(1-3x+3x^2-3x^6) = \sum\limits_{n=0}(a_nx^n)
$$

$$
(1-3x+3x^2) = \sum(a_nx^n) * (1-3x+3x^2-3x^6)
$$

Then say we are given some closed recursive equation for $a_n$

(The above example probably does not have one).

Of course I can write out a couple of these expansions to see a pattern for $a_0, a_1, a_3, ...$

And even if I can see this pattern, I can't generalize $a_n$ based on a pattern I see.

So how can I prove that this sequence follows a given recursive equation? I assume by induction, but how?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there certainly is a closed-form solution.  Multiply through the right-hand side of your equation and set coefficients of equal powers of $x$ on the left and right-hand side of the equation equal to each other.  The result is the recursion

$$a_{n+6}-3 a_{n+5}+3 a_{n+4}-3 a_n = 0$$

This is a simple constant-coefficient equation, which is attacked by letting $a_n = A r^n$ for some $r$ and $A$.  $r$ satisfies

$$r^6-3 r^5+3 r^4-3=0$$

You can solve this numerically and [get $6$ roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20r%5E6-3%20r%5E5%2b3%20r%5E4-3=0%20,%20r&t=crmtb01): two real, and 2 pairs of complex conjugate roots.  Label the roots $r_k$, $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $; the solution is then

$$a_n = A_1 r_1^n + A_2 r_2^n + A_3 r_3^n + A_4 r_4^n + A_5 r_5^n + A_6 r_6^n$$

We may then find the $A_k$ from initial conditions, also derived from the original equation for the lower powers of $x$:

$$\begin{align} a_0 &= 1 \\ a_1-3 a_0 &= -3\\ a_2 - 3 a_1 + 3 a_0 &= 3\\ a_3 - 3 a_2 + 3 a_1 &= 0\\ a_4 - 3 a_3 + 3 a_2 &= 0\\ a_5 - 3 a_4 + 3 a_3 &= 0\\ \end{align}$$

This leads to a $6 \times 6$ system of equations for the $A_k$.  But there you have your (effectively) closed form for $a_n$.

**EDIT**

One thing you could do is Taylor expand $(1-3x+3x^2)/(1-3x+3x^2-3x^6)$ into a power series.  And when I put up the first few terms, I get

$$1+3 x^6+9 x^7+18 x^8+27 x^9+27 x^{10}-72 x^{12}+O\left(x^{13}\right)$$.

Now, I can reproduce these coefficients with my closed-form solution to $a_n$ above, as prescribed.  In fact, using Mathematica, I demonstrated precisely that.  I was a little worried that using numerical approximations to the roots might lead to inaccuracies that would propagate into the Taylor coefficients, but in fact I obtained agreement to the precision with which I computed the roots $r_k$.  Such agreement would prove what you want to prove, I think.  If you have access to Mathematica, you really should try this out; it is nice to generate the Taylor coefficients and see them generated a completely different way.

Comment: Although I do appreciate your answer, is there a way to prove it without doing the above?

Comment: @DillPixel: See my edit.